# How to get Select Field Value Lenght in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my example code if anyone can please explain just tell me the syntax of MySQL ...

```
SELECT s.sales_id,s.pid,s.quantity,IFNULL((SELECT i.invoice_id FROM
invoice AS i WHERE i.checkin_id NOT IN (SELECT crt.checkin_id FROM 
checkin_request_ticket as crt WHERE crt.salvage_part='1') AND 
i.invoice_id=s.sales_id),s.quantity) as checkquan
FROM sales as s
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: i want to count the "s.sales_id" field value length

Comment: `length(s.sales_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`length(s.sales_id)` gives the length